# Best way to change Twitter-API datetime's to a timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, strtotime

The Twitter API sends created_at datetimes like this:

```
"created_at": "Mon Jul 25 05:51:34 +0000 2011",
```

What's the best way to convert them in a timestamp and my local timezone (Europe/Zurich)? With strtotime(), I get results like *2013-11-08 20:07:00*

Thank you very much

Best regards

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$datetime = new DateTime("Mon Jul 25 05:51:34 +0000 2011");
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Zurich'));
echo $datetime->format('U');
```

See [`DateTime`](http://php.net/book.datetime), [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/datetime.format), [`DateTime::setTimezone()`](http://php.net/datetime.settimezone), [`DateTimeZone`](http://php.net/class.datetimezone) and [`date()`](http://php.net/function.date)